# Configure WinSCP PowerShell script to also include a private key

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I would like to add a private key to the code found from the WinSCP website.
Based on https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_delete_after_successful_download

```
# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "example.com"
    UserName = "user"
    Password = "mypassword"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx..."
}
 
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
 
# Connect
$session.Open($sessionOptions)
```

How can I achieve this and where could I fit this in?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`SessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#sshprivatekeypath) (or [`SessionOptions.SshPrivateKey`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#sshprivatekey)):

```powershell
# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "example.com"
    UserName = "user"
    SshPrivateKeyPath = "C:\path\to\mykey.ppk"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx..."
}
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly.. many thanks.